# How to make gradle dependencies intellij idea "import from gradle" friendly?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

The original gradle dependencies statements looks like this:

```
dependencies {
        testImplementation project(":graphics").sourceSets.test.output
        testImplementation project(":base").sourceSets.test.output
        testImplementation project(":controls").sourceSets.test.output
        testImplementation project(":swing").sourceSets.test.output
}
```

IntelliJ Idea (2022.3) won't import the dependencies for the project.

Removing the `sourceSets.test.output` makes the import work, but I can't alter the build flow logic.

How can I rewrite it so Intellij will auto-import the dependencies and the build flow works the same?

Comment: What error message would the IDEA show when it fails to import the Gradle? Can you share the whole error message?

Comment: There's no error, it just doesn't configure the dependencies.